# Transaction timeout fails on read only transaction calling a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, jpa, apache-camel, hikaricp

I have encountered a very random problem with transaction timeout failing to fire in one instance. Our stack uses springboot+camel+jpa
We use hikari connection pooling.

I am calling a stored procedure from my service class. The stored procedure only fetches data from different views. There is no insert or update from stored procedure.  The method calling stored procedure is annotated with `Transactional` as follows

@Transactional(readonly=true, timeout=25)

I have verified that the timeout works and has fired in the past as I can verify from my logs SQLTimeoutException.
But two days back, it was observed that for once, the timeout did not happen, and it left an open transaction in the dayabase, causisng database logs to be full.

Can anyone point me as to why it failed just randomly? Is there any other way preferred over this to setting the timeout for this stored procedure call? How can I debug the cause for this timeout failure?
Also does using transaction (`readonly=true`) cause any problem?

As additional information the stored procedure is quite complex and uses multiple views and left joins to extract data.

Comment: If it's only reading, why is it locking stuff?

Comment: Using a transaction with SNAPSHOT isolation helps with consistant reports.
SET XACT_ABORT ON is more likely to rollback a failed transaction. I have no idea how to set this with the OP's stack.

Comment: Make sure you always dispose your objects correctly, then the connection and transaction will nearly always be closed properly

Comment: @siggemannen The stored procedure is quite complex. It creates many temporary tables, with inserts updates and deletes. Can this be an issue?